# Clever algorithm for checking on equality

Tags: algorithm, search

We need to implement next feature:

Suppose we have a list of some objects.
We need to say what objects are the same and what are not.
Suppose 1 is equal to 2 and 2 is equal to 5.
So 1 is equal to 5 and we don't need to check them.

Does this algorithm exist?
Any ideas would be very great.

Comment: So what are the inputs to this algorithm, and what are its outputs?

Answer (score 3):

I think this can be thought of as having sets of elements which are equal. And IMO Disjoint Set Data Structure will be very efficient in maintaing such set of records. The basic idea is to first put every element as a seperate set, whenever you encounter a equality relation you take the set to which those elements belong and merge them. The run time for merge and lookup are sub-logarithmic if you use path compression. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure

Answer (score 1):

You want a [Disjoint Set strucutre](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) with path compression.  It's very simple to implement, and the performance is close to O(1).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a graph where the vertices are the objects and there's an edge between known equal objects, then every object connected to another object is also equal. So, to test if object A equals object B, you are testing if a path exists between A and B in that graph.

You can use any graph searching algorithm to do this. [Depth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) would be a good start.

If you want to find all connected pairs then you could use [Tarjan's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan%27s_strongly_connected_components_algorithm) to find all strongly connected components. Within each component, all objects are equal.

Comment: Tarjan's algorithm is for strongly connected components, I believe here graph is undirected and normal DFS suffices to find connected components

Comment: @sdcvvc: An undirected graph is trivially converted to a directed graph (add directed edge `vu` for each undirected edge `uv`). DFS suffices, but is inefficient O(V^2) to find all equal pairs.

Comment: Tarjan's algorithm does not have better complexity (both have O(V+E)) and is a bit harder to implement than DFS, while gives the same result.